# Can't trigger ended event with Plyr.js

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, plyr.js

I'm trying to implement https://github.com/sampotts/plyr#events but cannot trigger the ended state with the embeds using the addEventListener() method as I'm not using jquery. I'm currently trying to just simply display a msg when it's over. but it doesn't even get displayed on console.

I have created the element and exposed it to public using this code

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => { 
  // == Plyr JS ==
  const player = new Plyr('#player', {
    autoplay: false,
  }); 
  // Expose
  window.player = player;

});
```

I'm already loading new sources using the player.source within the public code.

Tried to call the event state using this. But I can't even get the log on console.

```
player.addEventListener('ended', () => {
  console.log(`Video is finished`)
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've included the line where I wait for the DOM to load and it worked.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
 const player = new Plyr('#player', {
  // player options
  }); 

 player.on('ended', event => {
    // functions that I'd like to add
  });
```

Turns out the .on function mentioned on the documentary wasn't jQuery's `.on()` and it works just as fine `.addEventListener` if I kept it within the `DOMContentLoaded`